# Writing the possible values of "x" in an equation or making a solution check at the end?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Should I write the possible values of an equation or make a solution check at the end?

For example, I have the equation:

$ln (x^4-25x^2) - ln(x^2) = 0$

Should I first write that:

$x^4 -25x^2 >0$

$x^2 > 0$

So: $ x< (-2)* \sqrt{6} $  and  $ x>2* \sqrt{6} $

I think it's easier to do this and then just see if the solution fits the interval, rather than make a verifying check at the end. :)

Comment: Admit that the domain is valid and then write $\ln (x^4-25x^2) =\ln(x^2) $. Exponentiate both sides. Solve for $x$ and check if there is valid solutions.

Comment: Should I write it as "domain", even though it isn't a function?

Comment: When you write an equation, you look for the intercept of a function with the $x$ axis. So, ...

Comment: also keep in mind $e^{0} = 1$